# Electron: Inject script from a npm package

Tags: electron, preload

I'm loading a webpage via http, and this webpage renders a webview like this (using react)

```
render() {
  return <webview
    nodeintegration="true"
    preload={`file://${what_should_i_put_here}`}
    src={`some_website`}
  />;
}
```

I would like to `import preloadScript from 'npmPackage/lib/preloadScript.js'`, and inject the preloadScript into the webview.

Is that achievable?

Comment: what prevents you to put physical path to script in preload?

Comment: 1/ Tried relative paths as per the docs, doesn't work (there's an issue about that). 2/ I'm using create-react-app, and `__dirname` gives `/` because of the webpack config. 3/ I obviously don't want to hardcode the absolute path `/path/to/file.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> __dirname gives / because of the webpack config

is obviously part you may need adjust. So 1. either main process correctly resolve path and send to ipc, then react component picks up render cycle or 2. configure wepback's external to not to wrap up node's internal so renderer directly access those context.

Comment: 2 is not possible because of CRA. Concerning 1, after sending __dirname to the renderer process, I'd need to preload `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../../node_modules/path/to/file.js')}`, right? How would this work in production mode, after I built the app (no node_modules anymore)

Comment: You are confused between produced result of CRA doesn't have any node_modules bundle. For electron, it is allowed case to have node_modules path in production build. You may need adjust config of CRA to properly expose preload files or find some way other around - I don't think default config of CRA supports all electron side target as CRA intended to produce builds for web browser.